# jquery - fastest selector knowing the first 2 parents

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, selector

I have the following setup:

```
 var el = $("#overParent");
 // Do whatever with el here.
 var cls = $(".valueElement", "#parent"); // Get elements with class valueElement inside element with id parent
 // Do whatever
```

This is working but I was wondering if I can make this faster. I know that `#parent` is an element inside the `#overParent` which is already selected. Can I somehow use this to scan only the el `#overparent` for `#parent` then get the elements with the specified class?

Something like: `$(".valueElement", "#parent", el)` but according to documentation `$` takes only 2 parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just stick with the regular id selector:

```
$('#element');
```

It's still the fastest, even if you already have the parent element selected: http://jsperf.com/id-test-123

I'm just guessing here, but I think browsers use a lookup table to find elements by their id attribute.

Answer (score 2):

If you are finding an element by ID then using just:

```
var $element = $('#id');
```

without providing any context to search will always
be the fastest way.

Similarly here where you are providing an ID as a context for your search then `"#parent"` is the fastest selector. You could theoretically use `"#overParent > #parent"` to achieve what you mean but it would actually mean more work to do and would be slower.

Comment: Yes... in general you are right. But in this case I already have the parent selected.

Comment: It doesn't matter. Telling jQuery to look for `#parent` in a specific part of the DOM (whether you already have that specific part selected or not) would be slower then just asking for the element with a specific ID, which is always the fastest query.

Answer (score 1):

Selectors like `'#theId'` don't make jQuery scan the document, as it uses `document.getElementById`.

If you want to look for an element knowing its id, even if you know its parent, **always** use `$('#theid')`.

In fact, if you provide the parent as context, jQuery will call `document.getElementById` **and** check after that that the parent contains the found element. This is thus much slower.

From the source code :

```
    // Speed-up: Sizzle("#ID")
    if ( (m = match[1]) ) {
        if ( nodeType === 9 ) {
            elem = context.getElementById( m );
            // Check parentNode to catch when Blackberry 4.6 returns
            // nodes that are no longer in the document #6963
            if ( elem && elem.parentNode ) {
                // Handle the case where IE, Opera, and Webkit return items
                // by name instead of ID
                if ( elem.id === m ) {
                    results.push( elem );
                    return results;
                }
            } else {
                return results;
            }
        } else {
            // Context is not a document
            if ( context.ownerDocument && (elem = context.ownerDocument.getElementById( m )) &&
                contains( context, elem ) && elem.id === m ) {
                results.push( elem );
                return results;
            }
        }
```

Similarly, if you want to select all elements with a class, don't specify the parent, this doesn't help.

In your case, as you seem to want to use the parent to restrict the set, simply use

```
$(".valueElement", "#parent");
```

Comment: Yes... in general you are right. But in this case I already have the parent selected.

Comment: @zozo Even when you have the parent selected, it's faster to just give the id. Adding the parent as context **adds** a check.

Answer (score 1):

according to the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/)...

```
var el = $("#overParent");
```

this is extremly efficient  thn having another selector attached to it....

> For id selectors, jQuery uses the JavaScript function document.getElementById(), which is extremely efficient. When another selector is attached to the id selector, such as h2#pageTitle, jQuery performs an additional check before identifying the element as a match.

Answer (score 1):

@Blender

If you are using classes and cache the context element it is faster providing the context:

http://jsperf.com/id-test-123/3